# How to close a connection with Retrofit, okhttp with Kotlin

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

after a Post request everything works fine!

On my NodeJS Express Server the request is recieved.
But after a few seconds the app is crashing with this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
                                                                                                    Process: com.nougatbits.nougatbitssmspushservice, PID: 7161
                                                                                                    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
                                                                                                        at okio.SocketAsyncTimeout.newTimeoutException(JvmOkio.kt:143)
                                                                                                        at okio.AsyncTimeout.access$newTimeoutException(AsyncTimeout.kt:162)
                                                                                                        at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:335)
                                                                                                        at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.kt:427)
                                                                                                        at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:320)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http1.HeadersReader.readLine(HeadersReader.kt:29)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:178)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:106)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:79)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@9efb696, Dispatchers.IO]
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
                                                                                                        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:188)
                                                                                                        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:143)
                                                                                                        at okio.InputStreamSource.read(JvmOkio.kt:90)
                                                                                                        at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:129)
```

I tried extending the timeout. This worked but this has only extended the error.
At the end the app is crashing.

Here is my code:

```
fun sendTheTextMessage(sender: String, message: String, date: String, receiver: String){



/*val textMessage = Message(
    sender = sender,
    message = message,
    date = date,
    receiver = receiver
)*/



try {

    // Create Retrofit
    /*
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.234:3001")
        .build()
        .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()

     */

    val httpClient: OkHttpClient.Builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .callTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    val builder: Retrofit.Builder = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.234:3001")

    builder.client(httpClient.build())

    val retrofit = builder.build()


    // Create Service
    val service = retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)

    // Create JSON using JSONObject
    val jsonObject = JSONObject()
    jsonObject.put("sender", sender)
    jsonObject.put("message", message)
    jsonObject.put("date", date)
     jsonObject.put("receiver", receiver)

    // Convert JSONObject to String
    val jsonObjectString = jsonObject.toString()

    // Create RequestBody ( We're not using any converter, like GsonConverter, MoshiConverter e.t.c, that's why we use RequestBody )
    val requestBody = jsonObjectString.toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull())

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        // Do the POST request and get response
        val response = service.createEmployee(requestBody)

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {

                try {
                    // Convert raw JSON to pretty JSON using GSON library
                    val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
                    val prettyJson = gson.toJson(
                        JsonParser.parseString(
                            response.body()
                                ?.string() // About this thread blocking annotation : https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3255
                        )
                    )

                    Log.d("Pretty Printed JSON :", prettyJson)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    response.errorBody()?.close()
                } finally {
                    response.body()?.close();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("RETROFIT_ERROR", response.code().toString())

            }
        }
        response.body()?.close()
    }
} catch (e: Exception ) {

    Log.d("Error", e.localizedMessage)
}

}
```

Extending the Timeout. But at the the app is still crashing :(

Comment: Do you send a response back from your server?

Answer (score 0):

```
val httpClient: OkHttpClient.Builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .callTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectionPool(ConnectionPool(0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
```

Try adding the connection pool in the OkhttpBuilder.
More info [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3146).